# Jasypt: How to decrypt property stored in Map<String, String>?

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file, jasypt

Collegues, could you help to decrypt password (it is a value in `stmCredentials` map) from properties file using jasypt.

I have next strings in my properties file:

```
creds.users={testLogin: 'ENC(w0H***pgsj)'}
user2.login = ENC(9j3fHz5c****cLRCVvLTQmr5)
user2.pass  = ENC(w0HxpKq7V3Lf***g3zs/hpgsj)
```

I run the test in debug mode:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@Slf4j
public class CredentialsTest {


    @BeforeClass
    public static void beforeClass(){
        System.setProperty("jasypt.encryptor.password", "C*******L");
    }


    @Autowired
    StmCredentials stmCredentials;


    @Value("${user2.login}")
    private String user2Login;
    @Value("${user2.pass}")
    private String user2Pass;

    @Test
    public void getCredspairs() {
        HashMap<String, String> credspairs = stmCredentials.getCredspairs();
    }
}
```

After run I have next values in variables:

```
credspairs:
  key: "testLogin" 
  value:"ENC(w0HxpKq7V3LfEPsU5mbd0Vg3zs/hpgsj)" //it wasn't decrypt =(
```

and (**attention!**)

```
user2Login = testLogin   //it was decrypt
user2Pass = K1212Zrde
```

It seems that something wrong in my properties file, in `creds.users` property. I tried to use "single quotes, double quotes", but it doesn't help.

`StmCredentials` bean looks like:

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class StmCredentials {

    @Value("#{${creds.users}}")
    private HashMap<String, String> credspairs;
    public HashMap<String, String> getCredspairs() {
        return credspairs;
    }
    public void setCredspairs(HashMap<String, String> somedata) {
        this.credspairs = somedata;
    }
}
```

How to decrypt password stored in `StmCredentials` (value)? 
Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

I don't think Jasypt can detect and decrypt values from properties file in this manner (from the limited span of my knowledge). You can try putting this in `application.yml` file if you can. It should work there. Anyway, here's what we can do:

This actually isn't the solution but a possible workaround. We can create a class to decrypt the values ourselves if Jasypt automatically won't do it for us.

```
import org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.PooledPBEStringEncryptor;
import org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.SimpleStringPBEConfig;

public class MyStringEncryptor {
    private StringEncryptor encryptor;

    public MyStringEncryptor(String password) {
        PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
       SimpleStringPBEConfig config = new SimpleStringPBEConfig();
       config.setPassword(password);
       config.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
       config.setKeyObtentionIterations("1000");
       config.setPoolSize("1");
       config.setProviderName("SunJCE");
       config.setSaltGeneratorClassName("org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator");
       config.setStringOutputType("base64");
       encryptor.setConfig(config);
       this.encryptor = encryptor;
    }

    public String encrypt(String message) {
        return encryptor.encrypt(message);
    }

    public String decrypt(String message) {
        return encryptor.decrypt(message);
    }
}
```

Now we can create an object of `MyStringEncryptor` class and use the method `decrypt` to decrypt our desired value.

```
MyStringEncryptor encryptor = new MyStringEncryptor("mysecretpass"); // You can pass the password from properties file using @Value

String decryptedValue = encryptor.decerypt(encrypted-message);
```